# Forms Authentication not allowing access to landing page

Tags: asp.net, iis, form-authentication

I'm having problems with my asp.net 4.0 Web Forms application not allowing anonymous access to landing page.

My problem is the following

- If I access the site using URL "localhost/website/default.aspx", the default page is shown.  When I click on the login button on the page, the users is logged in as expected.
- If I access the site using URL "localhost/website", the user is taken directly to the login page.  The expected behavior is that the "default.aspx" page will be displayed.

I'm testing on Windows 7/64 using VS2010.  My web.config section looks like

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name=".xxxxADAuthCookie" loginUrl="~/Login.aspx" timeout="45"
         defaultUrl="~/secure/Default.aspx" slidingExpiration="true" />
</authentication>
<membership defaultProvider="MyADMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add attributeMapUsername="sAMAccountName" name="MyADMembershipProvider"
         type="xxxxx.xxxxxxFormsAuthenticationMembershipProvider" />
  </providers>
</membership>
<authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
  <allow users="*" />
</authorization>
  <location path="default.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="?" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

Comment: Make sure that default.aspx is at the top of your default document list.

Comment: Do you want to access the default.aspx before log in?

Comment: Yes.  That is what the users want.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Web.config: defaultUrl="~/secure/Default.aspx" The "/secure/" folder not mentioned in the hierarchy you described above.

Another option: try to force default routing in Global.asax.cs (something like this:)

```
    routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "website", action = "default", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

Comment: Should have clarified things.  I have a web forms app not MVC

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can set your **loginUrl**=**defaultUrl**.

```
<forms name=".xxxxADAuthCookie" loginUrl="~/secure/Default.aspx" timeout="45"
     defaultUrl="~/secure/Default.aspx" slidingExpiration="true" />


<location path="login.aspx">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

Try it again.